# Upgrade MSDE to SQL Server or another version of MSDE

Tags: sql-server-2008, msde

We have a production application which installs MSDE on user system in production and application access that as local database. Now we are migrating user systems with Windows 7 and application technology to .NET. We are planning to upgrade the MSDE also as it is a version 8.00.760 (I am checking in Add Remove Programs properties). I am confused what should be the version? Do we need to update to SQL Server 2008 or is there higher versions of MSDE also?

I don't have to take data backup from old MSDE and no need to worry about that part.

If we need to go to SQL Server 2008, which version would be the best for my case? I have around 200 users. Do we need to buy the product from somewhere (like Microsoft)

What would be cost for this if yes? And do we buy a bulk licence or its on basis of user?

Can you please advice me on this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MSDE** was the "local-only" version of SQL Server **2000** - there is no more recent version of MSDE.

As of SQL Server **2005**, the free version (which you can legally use **FOR FREE** - even for commercial applications) are called **SQL Server Express**. The current version is SQL Server **2012** Express (with the 2014 version coming out soon) - I would strongly recommend to use that version (and not use another already 5-year old system like SQL Server 2008).

Those are still a server-product that should be installed on a central server - but you can also use it locally on a PC. The main limitation is that the Express versions only support 1 CPU, up to 1 GB of RAM, and have a database size limit (up to 4 GB for 2005/2008, up to 10 GB for 2008 R2/2012).

[See this Microsoft site for more information on SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx)

If you have an issue with those limitations - then yes, you must purchase official licenses for SQL Server - either from Microsoft or from an authorized reseller. The different options and prices are just way too broad to list here - you'll have to ask Microsoft or a reseller for a quote

Comment: Thank You! We have to stick with SQL Server 2008 because the vendor who is goving us product has SQL Server 2008. Even though SQL Server 2010/12 will support all features of 2008 but still I believe My manager would like to stick with 2008 for now. The application is a kind of medium size and database should not go more than 1 GB. I went through the site you suggested. Its is mentioned that its free. When you said issue with limitaions, I don't see any limitation. I did some more research and see the site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275(v=sql.100).aspx.

Comment: So legal means we can distribute the Setup to any number of production users. Thanks for the advice.